# Paramiko ssh banner lost for server with OpenSSH4.3

Tags: python, paramiko, openssh

I have bunch of ntp appliances which I am trying to access from some jump server, and need to parse the ssh banner that is presented by the appliance.

For the servers running with OpenSSH5.5 the banner is returned by `client._transport.get_banner()` which ultimely set by `_parse_userauth_banner` method in `auth_handlers.py`.

Here the paramiko debug logs

```
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.300] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xd5fb5e10
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.300] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.366] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5
INF [20201201-15:05:35.366] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.5)
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.420] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:['aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour128', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'arcfour', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.421] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.421] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.421] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.422] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha1
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.422] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.528] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Got server p (2048 bits)
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.782] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGexSHA256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.783] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.785] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key b'f84e82ewewjhwhrvhgyghwe7636vdsv' in /myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.891] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20201201-15:05:35.966] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Auth banner: b'\n*******************************************************************************\n*   Welcome to the Sonoma_D12 CDMA SSH console on: \n*******************************************************************************\n\n'
INF [20201201-15:05:35.967] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEB [20201201-15:05:35.967] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.023] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.023] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.079] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.090] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.090] thr=1   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.133] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
DEB [20201201-15:05:36.136] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Dropping user packet because connection is dead.
```

***Raw ssh handshake logs***

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 552 bytes for a total of 573
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<4096<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 597
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 270/512
debug2: bits set: 2021/4096
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:10263
debug2: bits set: 2008/4096
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1141
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 1193
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: Wrote 68 bytes for a total of 1261
debug3: input_userauth_banner

*******************************************************************************
*   Welcome to the Sonoma_D12 CDMA SSH console on
*******************************************************************************
```

However for the servers running the OpenSSH4.3 the call to `client._transport.get_banner()` returns because in this case `_parse_userauth_banner` method is never called.

```
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.474] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x1e928f50
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.475] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.883] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
INF [20201201-15:07:04.883] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_4.3)
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.973] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none'] server compress:['none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.974] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.974] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.974] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.974] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha1
DEB [20201201-15:07:04.974] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20201201-15:07:05.362] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Got server p (2048 bits)
DEB [20201201-15:07:11.836] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexGex specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
DEB [20201201-15:07:11.837] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20201201-15:07:11.839] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key b'f84e82ewewjhwhrvhgyghwe7636vdsv' in /myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
DEB [20201201-15:07:12.019] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20201201-15:07:12.545] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEB [20201201-15:07:12.546] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20201201-15:07:12.647] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEB [20201201-15:07:12.647] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEB [20201201-15:07:12.748] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20201201-15:07:13.387] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
DEB [20201201-15:07:13.388] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
```

As seen above the ***Auth banner*** is simply not being captured by paramiko, however if I login directly from terminal using the ssh command the login banner is presented.

***Raw ssh handshake logs***

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 552 bytes for a total of 573
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<4096<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 597
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 243/512
debug2: bits set: 2001/4096
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 528 bytes for a total of 1125
debug2: bits set: 2099/4096
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1141
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 1193
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: Wrote 68 bytes for a total of 1261
debug3: input_userauth_banner

*******************************************************************************
*   Welcome to the Tempus LX CDMA SSH console on:  Tempus LXCDMA.your.domain
*******************************************************************************
```

I have looked a quite a bit into it but it seems that this is boiling to protocal level and has something to do with open ssh version.

So can anyone suggest any workaround here ?